# add mousewheel scroll to jcarousel (not lite)

Tags: jquery, mouse, jcarousel, mousewheel

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: true,
        scroll: 2
    });
});

</script>
```

How can I add a mousewheel scroll to my jcarousel plugin?
I have an up and down arrow in my vertical carousel
and would like to be able to use the mousewheel as well
to scroll up and down.

Also, I would like it to work on mobile platforms, but
that's another issue.

Thanks for the help